# Does Coil support SVG animations from string source?

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I convert my svg source from `String` to `ByteArray` and then I want to display my image (which has animation) using Coil.

```
val decoded: ByteArray = Base64.decode(source, Base64.DEFAULT)



AsyncImage(
                        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                            .data(decoded)
                            .decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory())
                            .build(),
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
```

Image display but without animation. Does Coil support animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that Coil doesn't support animation and it's not likely to be supported:
https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/issues/1405